# Wordpress custom post type filtering

Tags: php, wordpress

Having a little trouble here hoping someone can help. I've been reading around and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. What I have done so far is create a custom post type in Wordpress for a product which has two non-hierarchical taxonomies (colour and style).

I can display them fine but I want to be able to do is filter them via links in the sidebar. So you can just select products in certain colour AND certain style and it will display them. E.g if it was cars display all red cars in a saloon style.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [OTW Portfolio Light](https://wordpress.org/plugins/otw-portfolio-light/) plugin can achieve what you're looking for. Kindly note that this plugin works only with the default custom post type that comes built-in with the plugin. (It is *otw-portfolio*, if I'm not wrong). You'll have to customize it suit your need.

Comment: Thanks I might take a look at that. I was hoping to do it with my current custom posts since it must be possible. Searching and filtering seems like it should be something pretty standard.

Comment: That's not what I suggested. You could savage the code in the plugin and modify it to suit your need. Its just a matter of converting the custom post type in the plugin to yours.